# Opencart override engine issue

Tags: php, opencart

In OpenCart 2.0 I am extending a model `ModelAccountOrder` with override engine. I've successfully modified the existing method `getOrder($order_id)` functionality by overriding it but when I created a new method in my child class then `$this->db` is not accessible there and I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'DB\stdClass' not found in system\library\db\mpdo.php on line 77

My child class `receivers_ModelAccountOrder` is in `override\receivers\catalog\model\account\order.php` and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Override Engine. This is an issue with the drivers shipped with Opencart 2.0 that has since been [patched](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/commit/9acc10a5fc680df263d028430881278fc523b229).

Unfortunately, there are MANY bugs in the core code like this. If you insist on developing for 2.0 at this early stage, I recommend keeping a close eye on their issue/revision lists.

Comment: There was an issue with mysql query i have fixed it, now everything is working fine.

Comment: You should still patch, so the error will be more forthcoming